# linux kbuild makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to compile and link in to  a single object file according to menuconfig choosen flags to compile different source files.

like ;

obj-$(config1) : sample.o (but it should build from sample_1.c)
obj-$(config2) : sample.o (but it should build from sample_2.c)

Is it possible through makefile or if it is not possible through linux kbuild any tricks to achieve this is highly appreciated.

rgds,
Sharanu

Comment: There are several ways to do this, none perfect. We need more information about your intentions/priorities. Why do you want to use the name `sample.o` for two different files?

Comment: I dont want to change the script file which loads the the modules since there are lot of dependencies. Instead it has to load a single module but built according to compilation directive.

Comment: any solution for this even not perfect...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing I know of to do this automatically, however, Kbuild files are Makefiles, so you can use Makefile conditionals in them.  You could do something like this:

```
ifneq ($(findstring $(config1),"ym"),)
  $(obj)sample.o: $(obj)sample_1.o
      $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
else
ifneq ($(findstring $(config2),"ym"),)
  $(obj)sample.o: $(obj)sample_2.o
      $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@
endif
endif

obj-($config1) += sample.o
obj-($config2) += sample.o
```

Hope this helps

John